# Checked the checkboxes while editing using multiselect jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

Can any one tell me how to check checkboxes while editing using multiselect jquery plugin?
When i clicked this edit button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp9iu.png)
Here's a pic before editing:
A modal pop ups that have languages checkbox unchecked:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O50ze.png)

Initially it was uncheck but when checked it shows below dropdown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jn2R.png)

when clicking on edit button, i retrieve all data from db and wants to show it on language dropdown. i.e only those languages will checked that i have in retrive agianst particular record.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcasm.png)

Here's my code:

```
 $('#lang').attr('checked',true);
    $('#langList').show();
    $('#language').multiselect({
        columns: 1,
        placeholder: 'Select Languages',
        search: true,
        selectAll: true
    });
        $(lngArr).each((index,element) => {
            $(lng_all).each((i,e) => {
                if(element == e)
                { $('.ms-options').children('ul').children('li').val('ms-opt-'+index).parent('li').attr('selected',true);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please add relevant plugins

Comment: What `edit` button? You mean the `select all` link?

Comment: Sure, but where is YOUR reply and code?

Comment: I have data in db, in languages column like zulu,Zuhang. I fetched it from db and i want to see this user when user click on edit button to edit these languagies. So the data in  db will retrieve and those checkboxes will checked

Comment: 1. Show some code. 2. What edit button. You do not show any edit button

Answer (score 0):

You can apply following logic for set the data in multiselect.

```
 let newdata = [];
 let selectedData=[];
 $(lngArr).each((index,element) => {
 newdata.push({ label: element, value: element});
        $(lng_all).each((i,e) => {
            if(element == e)
            { 
              selectedData.push({label: e, value: e});
            }
        });
    });
 
 $("#langList").multiselect('dataprovider', newdata);
 $("#langList").multiselect('selectAll', false);
 $("#langList").multiselect('select', selectedData);
 $("#langList").multiselect("refresh");
```

So in above `lngArr` is main array list which contains whole language list.`lng_all` should contains selected value of array.

for set a data in multiselect its required label and value array so I just stored the data in that format for both data.

So `newdata` contains all the language array and `selectedData` contains selected data of the language and its set the details automatically.

Comment: Thanks, its working fine but $("#langList").multiselect('select', selectedData); is not working

Comment: @GhulamGhousQadri I update my answer add `.multiselect("refresh")`.